# Function with condition to calculate output

Tags: python, pandas, function

I have the following code, where I want to compute the phase of flight of a particular aircraft. In this regard, I'm trying to compute it using conditions with df.loc function. Here is what I've tried so far. Unfortunately the output of this code is not accurate, because the df['pphase'] (previous flight phase), is not working properly. The way I've done, the pphase will not be computed correctly. Would you please help me figure out the correct coding?

```
#phases of flight:
# 1)engine stopped
# 2)taxi-out
# 3)take-off
# 4)rejected take-off
# 5)second segment
# 6)Initial Climb
# 7)Climb
# 8)Cruise
# 9)Descent
# 10)Approach
# 11)Final Approach
# 12)Go Around
# 13)Landing
# 14)Taxi-in

def compute_flight_phase(df_to_be_computed):

    # VALUE OF THE PREVIOUS PHASE
    # ==============================
    df['flight_phase'] = 0
    df['pphase'] = df['flight_phase'].shift(1)

 # 1) ENGINE STOPPED
    # =================
    df.loc[df['radioHeight-2a'] < 50, 'flight_phase'] = 1

    # 2) TAXI-OUT
    # ===========
    df.loc[(df['eng_stopped'] == 0) & (df['wOW-3a'] == 1) & (df['eng_takeoff'] == 0) &
           (((df['pphase'] < 5) | ((df['eng_2started'] == 1) & (df['groundSpeed-1a'] < df['gsc_min'])) |
             ((df['pphase'] == 14) & ((df['eng_cruise'] == 1) | (df['conf'] > df['conf'].shift(-1)))))),
           'flight_phase'] = 2

(....)
```

Comment: Why are you passing df_to_be_computed to the function then processing using another (global) DF?

Comment: @user19077881, because I wanted to create a def function and iterate over it with the rest of the code.

Comment: Is that a state machine written in pandas?

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa, yes.

Answer (score 0):

In my thought, you might choose the wrong method to implement what you're trying to do. What you're trying to do is create a `pphase` column which is `1` size smaller than the `flight_phase` column right?

I suggest you to use `df['pphase'] = df['flight_phase] - 1` instead of `df['pphase'] = df['flight_phase].shift(1)`.

Since it's a more explicit expression than `pandas.DataFrame.shift` method. The `shift` method is designed to handle date-related data, but your `pphase` and `flight_phase` columns have no relations about date. Isn't it?

FYI, see [pandas official document](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) and [GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-shift/) for further interest, it explains pretty kind.

Comment: shift will just the index for non-date data.

Comment: Yeahp, @user19077881 is right.